# Свой auth-микросервис в случае использования OAuth2

Tags: auth, oauth2, openid

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в случае использования OAuth2(OpenId Connect, как средство соединяющее и авторизацию и аутентификацию) написания собственного сервиса аутентификации(endpoint которого допустим принимает креды и отдает токен) является неправильным и нужно использовать то, что предоставляет сервер авторизации? Т.е. делать редирект на сервер авторизации, но что если я хочу сделать кастомную страницу аутентификации?
P.S. Естественно полагая, что сервер авторизации в приложении уже используется для получения и валидации токена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Написания собственного сервиса аутентификации(endpoint которого допустим принимает креды и отдает токен) является неправильным -

> [OAuth](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) — открытый протокол (схема) авторизации, который позволяет предоставить
> третьей стороне ограниченный доступ к защищённым ресурсам пользователя
> без необходимости передавать ей (третьей стороне) логин и пароль.

Естественно вы не можете передать "креды" потому что вы не можете у себя их держать.

2. Нужно использовать то, что предоставляет сервер авторизации? Т.е. делать редирект на сервер авторизации, но что если я хочу сделать кастомную страницу аутентификации? P.S. Естественно полагая, что сервер авторизации в приложении уже используется для получения и валидации токена. - **ДА**

PS. Воспользуйтесь готовым [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/). На изучение потратите не много времени но получите готовый сервер с исходниками бесплатно.

Comment: Да, мы используем keycloak, но мне кажется, что очень костыльно. У нас есть микросервис auth-service(для логина, регистрации и логаута), который принимает креды, делает запрос в кейклок, и возвращает токен, т.е. кейклок здесь выступает как генератор и валидатор токенов, ну и хранилище юзеров, это же совсем неправильно?

Comment: Кейклок как генератор, да костыль но. По сути это отдельно сервис регистрации и авторизации, аутентификации. Если все нормально настроить не будет необходимости вашего микросервиса